# Admin-on-rest: Show/hide Form Tab Based On Input Selection

Tags: redux-form, admin-on-rest

Not sure if this is the best approach but I'm attempting to use dependsOn: [github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input] to hide/show form tabs. It sort of works, but the problem is when the form re-renders based on the correct DependentInput value being selected, the form tab label does not render, but the tab's components do. 
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

```
import { DependentInput } from 'aor-dependent-input';

export const StakeholderCreate = (props) => (
<Create {...props}>
  <TabbedForm>
    <FormTab label="general">
        <TextInput source="name" />
        <SelectInput label="Type" source="typeId"  choices={[
          { id: 'carrier', name: 'Carrier' },
          { id: 'distributor', name: 'Distributor' },
          { id: 'exporter', name: 'Exporter' }
    </FormTab>
    <DependentInput dependsOn="typeId" value="carrier">
      <FormTab label="market">
        <TextInput source="market_distance.market_Name" />
      </FormTab>
    </DependentInput>
  </TabbedForm>
</Create>
);
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the `DependentInput` code to understand how it grabs the current field value from the redux(-form) store, and replicate it in your own component.